# Printing quotation marks in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write an excel formula in Python so I can execute an excel API.

The issue is that I am trying to write something in quotations so using \ but I am getting \' instead of what I want '. My code is below.

```
j = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
h = []

for hh in j:
    h.append(str(('=IFERROR(FDS(B')+('%d')%hh+(',"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C')+('%d')%hh+('&",,,')+('\'CURRENCY=LOCAL\'')+('")')))

raw_data2 = {'EPS EST': h}
```

The issue is around the term `('\'CURRENCY=LOCAL\'')`. I want it to appear `'CURRENCY=LOCAL'` but currently it is printing `\'CURRENCY=LOCAL\'`.

Comment: One solution is to use double quotes: " 'CURRENCY=LOCAL' "

Comment: This won't fix the escape characters showing up, but your big long string construction would be a lot easier to understand if you used `str.format` instead of the `+` operator to concatenate things: `'=IFERROR(FDS(B{0},"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C{0}&",,,\'CURRENCY=LOCAL\'")'.format(hh)`

Answer (score 2):

Leading and traling `\` is just a representation for escaping just like `u` in unicode object it has not any effect on data- try as below

```
j = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
h = []

for hh in j:
    h.append(str(('=IFERROR(FDS(B')+('%d')%hh+(',"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C')+('%d')%hh+('&",,,')+("'CURRENCY=LOCAL'"+('")'))))
print h#See '\' is present
for t in h: #but here '\' is absent
    print t
```

Output-

```
['=IFERROR(FDS(B1,"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C1&",,,\'CURRENCY=LOCAL\'")', '=IFERROR(FDS(B2,"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C2&",,,\'CURRENCY=LOCAL\'")', '=IFERROR(FDS(B3,"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C3&",,,\'CURRENCY=LOCAL\'")', '=IFERROR(FDS(B4,"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C4&",,,\'CURRENCY=LOCAL\'")', '=IFERROR(FDS(B5,"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C5&",,,\'CURRENCY=LOCAL\'")']
=IFERROR(FDS(B1,"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C1&",,,'CURRENCY=LOCAL'")
=IFERROR(FDS(B2,"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C2&",,,'CURRENCY=LOCAL'")
=IFERROR(FDS(B3,"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C3&",,,'CURRENCY=LOCAL'")
=IFERROR(FDS(B4,"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C4&",,,'CURRENCY=LOCAL'")
=IFERROR(FDS(B5,"FE_ESTIMATE(EPS,MEAN,ANNUAL_ROLL,+1,"&C5&",,,'CURRENCY=LOCAL'")
```

Comment: You might want to explain the two parts of the issue: The escape character is showing up because the question's code is printing a `repr` of a string that contains both single and double quotes.